# asp.net how to evaluate a CheckBox in GridView after populating it from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox, evaluate

I have a gridview in which one of the datafields is a checkbox. I read the DB and populate the gridview. I also have a OnRowCommand item. When I Select a row I want to get the value of the checkbox and put it in a lable on the form.
HTML :

```
<asp:GridView ID="grv_Contacts" runat="server"
     DataKeyNames="Cntc_Id" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
     CssClass="myGrid" OnRowCommand="grv_Contacts_RowCommand">
     <Columns>
         <asp:CommandField SelectText="SEL"
             ShowSelectButton="True" ControlStyle-CssClass="btn btn-warning myBtn-xs">
             <ControlStyle Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Blue" Width="40px" />
         </asp:CommandField>
         <asp:BoundField DataField="Cntc_Id" HeaderStyle-CssClass="myHidden" ItemStyle-CssClass="myHidden">
         </asp:BoundField>
         <asp:BoundField DataField="Cntc_Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Cntc_Name">
             <HeaderStyle Width="180px" />
             <ItemStyle CssClass="myGridItemMaxWidth" HorizontalAlign="Right" Wrap="false" />
         </asp:BoundField>
         <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Cntc_Allowed_To_Edit" HeaderText="?Allowed" SortExpression="Cntc_Allowed_To_Edit" />
    </Columns>
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="my_Grid_Header" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#669999" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Code behind :

```
protected void grv_Contacts_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
   int my_Grv_Row_Index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
   CheckBox my_CBX = (CheckBox)(grv_Contacts.Rows[my_Grv_Row_Index].Cells[3].Controls[0]);
   lbl_Message.Text = my_CBX.Text;
}
```

I keep getting NULL in lbl_Message.Text
I debugged and added a watch on **my_CBX** and it showed its
value as : `{Text = "" Checked = true}`

So - how can I evaluate a ckeckbox in a gridview if it's checked or not...?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since you use a `CheckBoxField`, the GridView only shows a checkbox as a visual representation of a `bit` column from the database. So it does not have `Text` by default.
You can add a default `Text` property to the checkbox.

```
<asp:CheckBoxField Text="?Allowed" HeaderText="?Allowed"
```

So now if you use `lbl_Message.Text = my_CBX.Text;` it will show the value of the Text property.

But if you want to see if the checkbox is checked you use `Checked`.

```
lbl_Message.Text = my_CBX.Checked.ToString();
//or
if (my_CBX.Checked == true)
{
    lbl_Message.Text = "Checkbox is checked";
}
```

Comment: Oooooo, man! Thank you so much. I spent so much time on it and the answer was so simple. Thanks a bunch!!   I used: my_CBX.Checked.ToString() and it works just fine.